# Bootraps Querstion about javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Since the bootstrap already include the javascripts in js folder

I have some questions

1. including just bootstrap.min.js and the latest jQuery for plugin is sufficient enough for function that in the bootstrap website "like Modal Navbar carousel"
2. If I want to making these function working (like when we click navigate button, it change content web site), I need to add addition script to make it work right?

Comment: You should be able to test this yourself.

Comment: How about reading the http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/  before asking questions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Depending on what functions you want to add you may have to add a few lines to your javascript.

For example, if you want to enable a dropdown:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

If you want to enable scrollspy:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' })
```

Just look at the documentation for any information you might need.

Cheers.